# Command line warning D9002: ignoring unknown option '-std=c++11'

Tags: c++11, visual-studio-2013, cmake, compiler-warnings

In my **CMakeList.txt** file, I have the following in order to add c++11 supports:

> set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11")

This works fine under Mac with Xcode. However, I get the following warning message from Visual Studio. Any idea?

> Command line warning D9002: ignoring unknown option '-std=c++0x'

Other than the compile warning, the program gets compile and run with no problem. I am using VS2013. If I remove that single "set flag" line, the warning goes away.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The `-std=c++11` option is for GCC/CLang only, it is not available in Visual Studio. C++ 11 support in Visual Studio should be turned on by default. So, you should use this option for GCC-like compilers only:

```
if(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID MATCHES "GNU|Clang")
    set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11")
endif()
```

If you are using the latest versions of CMake you might try to use new compiler features mechanism : http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.1/manual/cmake-compile-features.7.html

Comment: How about /std:[c++14|c++17|c++latest] ?
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/std-specify-language-standard-version

Comment: “_should be turned on by default._” I hate this. Do not ever _assume the default_ in makefiles. See Karol Król’s answer and explicitly set the flag for MSVC.

Answer (score 4):

Microsoft Visual Studio Compiler (MSVC) has it own [set of compiler flags](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/std-specify-language-standard-version?view=vs-2019).
In short: The solution to fix the issue is to use following command instead the one you have used.

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} /std:c++17")
```

Answer (score 2):

Use target_compile_features to get CMake to add the correct compiler flag, for C++ 11, for whichever compiler you are using

```
target_compile_features(mylibrary PRIVATE cxx_std_11)
```

or

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
```